# sum of a geometric series with increasing constant

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I need to find the sum of **limited** series as follows:

$$S = i + (i-1)\cdot 2 + (i-2)\cdot2^2 + (i-3)\cdot2^3 + ... + 1\cdot2^{i-1}$$ for integer $i$ in which $i \ge 1$.

I tried some series and I found the similar series in which the constant (i.e. $i$ here) is increasing(decreasing) as well, but for them the geometric constant (i.e. 2 here) is smaller than 1 and the series are unlimited.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Yes I tried some series and I found the similar series in which the constant (i.e. $i$ here) is increasing(decreasing) as well, but for them the geometric constant (i.e. 2 here) is smaller than 1 and the series are unlimited.

Comment: Ok. Please, update your question and put those informations. You will get a better help when you inform your owns thoughts.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $\Sigma_{i=0}^nix^i$? If so , you can transform your problem into such a sum. Can you see how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Multiply by the ratio of the geometric sequence.

$$2S=i\cdot2 + (i-1)\cdot 2^2 + (i-2)\cdot2^3 + (i-3)\cdot2^4 + ... +2\cdot2^{i-1}+ 1\cdot2^{i}$$

Now you can subtract both expressions and get:

$$2S-S=[i-(i-1)]2 + [(i-1)-(i-2)]2^2 + ... +[2-1]2^{i-1}+ 1\cdot2^{i}-i$$

so,
$$S=2+2^2+2^3+...+2^{i-1}+2^i-i$$

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Thank you for your brilliant solution! :)

Comment: you are very welcome!